# How to dragdrop multiple svg-elements, using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need to move some SVG-elements, using the mouse.

For this, I began to use the d3 framwork. My problem is the following. I need to move some elements, that are grouped together like this, at the same time (as they were both selected):

```
<g transform="translate(10, 10)" id="158" class="draggable preview symbol" pointer-events="fill">
  <rect class="CDC300" x="80" y="100" width="41" height="41" fill="none"></rect>
  <line class="CDC300" x1="140" y1="120" x2="121" y2="120" fill="none"></line>
  <text class="CDC300" x="100" y="131" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="30px" font-family="sans-serif" stroke-width="0.3">T</text>
  <text id="20010" class="CDC400" x="75" y="125" text-anchor="end">=HTC+HSP1</text>
  <circle class="insertpoint" cx="140" cy="120" r="3"></circle>
  <circle class="pin" cx="140" cy="120" r="2"></circle>
</g>

<g transform="translate(180,20)" id="159" class="draggable preview symbol" pointer-events="fill">
  <rect class="CDC300" x="80" y="100" width="41" height="41" fill="none"></rect>
  <line class="CDC300" x1="140" y1="120" x2="121" y2="120" fill="none"></line>
  <text class="CDC300" x="100" y="131" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="30px" font-family="sans-serif" stroke-width="0.3">T</text>
  <text id="20010" class="CDC400" x="75" y="125" text-anchor="end">=HTC+HSP1</text>
  <circle class="insertpoint" cx="140" cy="120" r="3"></circle>
  <circle class="pin" cx="140" cy="120" r="2"></circle>
</g>
```

Of course, I could dragdrop them, using the dragging-function of d3 but...
I have no idea, how to move the two grouped "symbols", without loosing the initial transform.

I created a simple example on [JS-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Telefisch/wydqa9x3/37/):

any ideas? - there could be more symbols so any static variable isn't possible.

**UPDATE:**

My idea is to move the elements to a new group, drag this group and after dragging, move the elements back to the svg-area and remove the new group:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  d3.selectAll('.symbol')
  .on("mouseover", onMouseOver)
  .on("mouseout", onMouseOut)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragStart)
    .on("drag", dragging)
    .on("end", dragEnd));
})

var xpos = 0;
var ypos = 0;

function dragStart() {
  var movinggroup = d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .classed('moving', true);

  d3.selectAll('.draggable').remove()
    .each(function(){
      movinggroup.node().appendChild(d3.select(this).node());
    });
}

function dragging() {
  xpos = xpos + d3.event.dx;
  ypos = ypos + d3.event.dy;
  d3.select('.moving').attr("transform", "translate("+ xpos+ " " + ypos + ")");
}

function dragEnd() {
  console.log("dragEnd");
  var transform = getTranslation(d3.select('.moving').attr('transform'));
  var newX = transform[0];
  var newY = transform[1];

  d3.select('.moving').selectAll('.draggable')
    .each(function(){
      var transform2 = getTranslation(d3.select(this).attr('transform'));
      var xPos = transform2[0] + newX;
      var yPos = transform2[1] + newY;
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate('+ xPos + ' ' + yPos + ')');
      d3.select('svg')
        .node()
        .appendChild(d3.select(this).node());
  });
  d3.selectAll('.moving').remove();
}

function getTranslation(transform) {
  var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
  g.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", transform);
  var matrix = g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
  return [matrix.e, matrix.f];
}
```

Now I have a last problem...
The moment, I begin to drag, the elements sometimes jump to the cursor. How can I avoid this?

[Actual JS-fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/Telefisch/wydqa9x3/121/)

Thanks Carsten.

Comment: Isn't it an option for you to permanently keep one wrapping `g` element to use for the translations? It would simplify the code.

Comment: no, because the elements are selected individually. So first I had dragdrop on every single elements but meantime you can select multiple elments and move them around or delete them.

Comment: by now, I have another problem with calculationg the coordinates. This damn javascript sometimes makes a string out of the values. Is there any stable int or long variable possible in javascript?